# Unable to assign value to generically typed object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, index-signature

I am trying to assign a value to the property of a generically typed object passed into a function. The object structure is unknown in advance and the property name is dynamically provided to the function as a string argument. Typescript throws the error "Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'".

I have the following typescript code:

```
interface Value {
  [key: string]: any
}

interface SomeInterface<T> {
  key: string,
  value: T
}

function someFunction<T extends Value>({ key, value }: SomeInterface<T>) {
  value[key] = somevalue;
}
```

The line where I assign somevalue to value throws the error "Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'", even though I specifically created the index signature in the interface Value.

Why is this?

Comment: What about like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcUG8BQyyA2gNYQCeAXMgM5hSgDmAujXCBfgL776iRYiFAGUA9gFsIASXDR4SADwAVAHzICRctToNmAGkLIAbphw1lPPjCwgEYYGJB1JEAGK37jkAApcybX0TMxRuGnEpWUEFCEV0bAhVAEoNI1MEskoWZABeZAByWld0nHyAbisgA)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can call `someFunction` with a more specific type of `Value`.

```
someFunction<{'someKey': any}>(...);
```

In this case `string` can no longer be used to index `value`. Only `someKey` would be a valid index. You can rewrite `SomeInterface` in such a way, that it always has a key that can be used to index the value:

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
  key: keyof T,
  value: T
}
```

[Full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcUG8CwAUMsgNoDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gLp1whVEC%20RRUJFiIUAZQD2AWwgBJcNHhIAPABUAfMgLFklWruoSYyVQBoiJAG6YcdVXwGEYWEAjDAJIBtIgAxF24eIGrIEAAekCAAJvRoNhDqABS4BlSmyNbYKLx0kjLywkoQauoAlFoWGfEU1GzIALzeMpk4ANx8QA)

Answer (score 0):

If you make the generic type key of the object you want to assign value to then you easily have types for the key and corresponding value.

```
interface Value {
  [key: string]: any
}

function someFunction<T extends keyof Value>({ key, value }: {key:T, value:Value[T]}) {
  value[key] = value;
}
```